# FragmentManager recycled

Tags: java, android

I'm getting a warning `This FragmentManager should be recycled after use with #recycle()` and i'm trying to fix it. Any suggestions?

```
date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
               DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerDialogFragment(ChartingFragment.this);
               newFragment.show(ft, "date_picker_fialog");
           }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `FragmentManager` in the parameters instead of the `FragmentTransaction`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerDialogFragment(ChartingFragment.this);
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "date_picker_fialog");
}
```

The `FragmentTransaction` parameter is used when you're chaining actions, and doesn't work when showing the Dialog is the only action. It may be a bug, but regardless, it doesn't work that way.

Comment: It does work and you'll find the `FragmentTransaction` way even here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#BasicDialog - it's a bug of Lint that shows just a warning about creating FragmentTransactions but never using them because it did not know that `DialogFragment#show()` is actually using them the right way.

Comment: @zapl Ahh, true, didn't notice it was a Lint error. According to the bug report on Adam's post, it was fixed recently, so shouldn't be a problem anymore if ADT is up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this google issues](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52771) page, this was a bug that has already been fixed. Try updating ADT. Mentioned again in [this post](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42788) also.

Comment: even 2 bugs in 1 as explained [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42660#c1)